# Huntmaster guides aliens hunting humans, but has agenda

Tags: story-identification

I don't recall the name or the author, but the story involves giant aliens being taken on hunting parties against humans on Earth. The guns used shrink the soldiers, men etc for collection and the Huntmaster guides them around. The people of Earth manage to adapt some of the technologies the aliens use, as the goal of the Huntmaster is to slowly acclimate the Earth to the entry of attacking aliens, much like a body learning how to fight off an infection and recover (rather than dying immediately due to a swift and sudden overwhelming attack).

The story also involves the technologies merging enemy soldier's flesh to metal (which slowly poisons them, making them apprehensive about handling them) and some sort of power wave accidentally triggered that allows a low-level telepathy throughout the human race, allowing others to see your mood and perspectives - this is demonstrated by two men arguing and realising both points of view from this.

Comment: This question has been closed as a Duplicate. Please note that this is not a censure and you'll keep getting points with upvotes. This just helps us tie the questions together in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least the "Hunt Master" and the shrink ray make me think of [*Come, Hunt an Earthman*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9833) (1973) by Philip E. High.

The alien guide to the alien hunters who seek to make trophies of humans is titled "Hunt Master"

> I allowed a long pause for this to sink in.  "All of you, no doubt, consider yourselves experienced.  I must warn you, however, that on this planet, previous experience must be wholly discounted.  I have been Hunt Master on many worlds and I can assure you that this is the most dangerous of all."

They use a shrink ray to take trophies:

> This time Kalvaninar was ready and the Pregnos made it characteristic zinging noise as he pulled the trigger.
>
> The Centurion tank which had fired on us came to an abrupt stop and developed a shimmering blue aura.  As we watched, it began to shrink visibly.
>
> Kalvaninar had learned quickly.  He took his time, alert for mines and, when he got there, his trophy was ready.
>
> The Prengos, besides being a weapon, alters the atomic construction of its target.  It reduces in mass and size without, in the case of mechanisms, reducing its efficiency.
>
> "Here!" Kalvaninar lifted the tank up triumphantly between thumb and forefinger.  "My first trophy on this planet.  This goes in the middle of my collection."

Humanity does learn to use alien technology; by the end of the story they have learned how to build shields at least as good as the aliens.  And Silverface (the Hunt Master) does admit that there was an aspect of training humanity to be able to fight off invasions, like an immune response:  (The Hunt Master is conversing with Walsh, a human leader.)

> "It is true you could well have gone under.  Your only assets were your superior shields and your native ingenuity, but I did not stand aside and watch.  As I told you, I had work to do and this *was*, therefore, your pigeon.
>
> "I don't quite follow."
>
> "This was a mass invasion, not a fatal or decisive invasion, but one that had to be countered."
>
> "Now I follow you even less."
>
> "The body of the universe suffered an onslaught, a mass onslaught. Refer it, if it helps, to your own body. This was a virus invasion. You have had a brief feverish cold which your normal defenses have just overcome."

Comment: Thank you! I recall the tank part as being at the very start - this is it ❤️